# Design a ckt which can make a beep sound 1sec on 1 sec off for 30 seconds and off for 2 minute 30 seconds

Tags: timer, sound

I need a ckt. in my design which can make a beep sound of 1 second ON 1 sec OFF for 30 seconds and no sound for 2 minute 30 seconds.. Can anyone design me one pls..

Thanks and regards..

Comment: This is not a free design service, if you want you can post what you have done so far, with some questions about it.

Comment: I have made the circuit using microcontroller.. I want to try it out using analog components..

Comment: Analog components? As in no 555 Timer? And really "ckt" and "pls" you saved a whopping 11 characters (or approx 3.8%). Is this how you would turn in a work or school assignment?

Answer (score 4):

The circuit is really simple:

[image]

The rest is firmware.